# Change return type from Integer to int without breaking backwards compatibility

Tags: java

I'm doing QA on a certain Java 7 API, that is in public usage as Open Source. My [Clirr](http://clirr.sourceforge.net/) report checks for backwards API compatibility. I got the following errors:

```
[ERROR] 7006: com.example.Foo: Return type of method 'public java.lang.Integer nameToUnicode(java.lang.String)' has been changed to int
[ERROR] 7006: com.example.Bar: Return type of method 'public byte getAnchorDelta()' has been changed to short
```

So this means that my developers changed the return type of `Foo` from `Integer` to `int`, and the return type of `Bar` was changed from `byte` to `short`. The method signatures stayed the same, so overloading is not an option.

1. Does this really break backwards compatibility? Or is Clirr giving me a false positive?
2. How can I unbreak backwards compatibility? Is this even possible without introducing new method names?

I have got a couple of other errors about return type changes (mostly some `void`s to `float`), but they are in `protected` methods, so I am going to ignore them.

Comment: You need to keep the same existing signatures if you wish to retain backward compatibility. You can add new ones, but the existing API has to remain identical to its previous incarnation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It clearly breaks backwards compatibility as your API's user may have had a code like:

```
if (nameToUnicode("...").equals(4)) { ... } // no such method
byte delta = getAnchorDelta(); // typecast required
```

Which won't compile from now on.

Considering that the new version of `getAnchorData()` returns a wider amount of values, you can't perform the transition without breaking backwards compatibility, as client's old code may not be suitable to accept all the possible values.

Also regarding your last statement:

> I have got a couple of other errors about return type changes (mostly some voids to float), but they are in protected methods, so I am going to ignore them.

If these methods are in `public` non-`final` classes, then you break backwards compatibility by doing so as well.

Answer (score 1):

Backward compatibility is definitely broken, as the expression stack is typed, on the result unboxing is done.

The second question is: whether a recompilation against the new API would suffice and deliver no errors.

Integer to int, though better style might now **propagate style warnings** on Integer usage in client software. Even when inferring types as in java 8 it should go well, except when immediately comparing with null:

```
if (nameToUnicode("ĉarma") == null)
```

And that is a very rare case.

With byte/short hands-on is needed. Also one might expect short values exceeding the byte range, or sign overflow for short values between 128 and 255.
Only if the logic is unchanged, the values still in -128 .. 127 all is functionally well.

Though not compilable, sources must be adapted.

---

***Providing backward compatibility:***

For existing binary jars: keep the old functions, `@Deprecated` and javadoc comments for new usage. Throwing IllegalStateException when out-of-range for short to byte.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what user3707125 wrote another problem might be if someone extends your class and overrides your method. Consider following example:

```
public class BaseClass {
    public Integer getInt() {
        return 1;
    }
}

public class MyClass extends BaseClass {
    @Override
    public Integer getInt() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

If you changed return type in BaseClass to int then MyClass will have a compilation error. So this breaks backward compatability. The same is when you change byte to short.